# Ruby string of bytes to array of integers?

Tags: ruby

I have a string represented like this in ruby: `"\x00\x00\xff"` How can I get an array of the integers? I'm abit confused about how to represent bytes properly.

For example, how can I transform that into an array like this?

```
[ 0, 0, 255 ]
```

**Update**

I've tried the examples below, and this is where I'm having trouble, like `"\x00\x00\xff".bytes` should work but I get this:

```
[92, 120, 52, 48, 92, 120, 102, 102, 92, 120, 53, 53]
```

Like each character is returning it's byte code instead of recognizing that they are separate bytes. How do I prevent that string "\x00\x00\xff" from interpreted as literally a string?

Comment: `"\x00\x00\xff".unpack('C3')` just to be complete.

Comment: @squiguy: or `"C*"` to avoid hardcoding. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = "\x00\x00\xff"
s.bytes # => [0, 0, 255]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [***`String#each_byte`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte) for this :

```
"\x00\x00\xff".each_byte.to_a
# => [0, 0, 255]
```